# Get fieldnames from List

Tags: apex, list

I have the next problem, when I get the output `susc` I get the next line:

> 12:59:48:144 USER_DEBUG [32]|DEBUG|Susc: DopplerListSubscriber__c:{Id=a0246000001nTMeAAM, Contact__c=00346000002O4YvAAK, DopplerList__c=a0046000001OvCGAA0}

The issue comes here, when I need to access this iterated List and read the fieldnames `Contact__c` without adding in an explicit way the fieldname to the `susc.Contact__c` call.

Here is the code:

```
Map<String, String> LookupFieldsMap = DopplerListCriteriasUtil.getAvailableLookupObjects();

// Build query with the availableLookups and Fields Mapping
List<DopplerListSubscriber__c> sobjList = Database.query(DopplerSQLBuilder.buildSOSQLDopplerListSubscriber(listId));

Map<String, String> dopplerWrapper = new Map<String, String>();

    for (DopplerListSubscriber__c susc : sobjList) {
        for (String loField : LookupFieldsMap.values()) {

            System.debug('Susc: ' + susc);
            System.debug('LookupFields: ' + loField);
        }
    }
```

How can I access the susc item List Array to get the fields without naming them, since if I do this I do see them:

```
String asd = susc.Contact__c;
```

Comment: `susc.get(loField)` perhaps?

Comment: No, it gives me the value of the field: `00346000002O4YvAAK` not the actual field name: `Contact__c. I made the same test`

Comment: I need that susc fieldname to actually compare with `loField` and in case both fieldnames are the same then do the logic.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question, then.

Comment: from the Susc: DopplerListSubscriber__c:{} I need to the the `Contact__c`, `id` etc, not its values, I need the labels or Keys, not the values of those.

Comment: Updated my answer.

Comment: Why do u need to compare them? `loField` holds the field API name, and `susc[loField]` is retriving that field value... No need to compare names here

Comment: `susc.getPopulatedFieldsAsMap()` then?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the way in case you don't trust Sobject class:-

```
Account acc = new Account(Name='Ashwani', AccountNumber='1234567');
String accString = JSON.serialize(acc);
Map<String,Object> attributes = (Map<String,Object>)JSON.deserializeUntyped(accString

for (DopplerListSubscriber__c susc : sobjList) 
{
     for (String loField : LookupFieldsMap.values()) 
     {

          Boolean shouldDoLogic = attributes.containsKey(loField);
          if(shouldDoLogic)
          {
                // Go Ahead
          }
     }
}
```

If you trust:

```
for (DopplerListSubscriber__c susc : sobjList) 
    {
         for (String loField : LookupFieldsMap.values()) 
         {

              Boolean shouldDoLogic = susc. getPopulatedFieldsAsMap.containsKey(loField);
              if(shouldDoLogic)
              {
                    // Go Ahead
              }
         }
    }
```

*You can tweak the above logic to get the desired result.*

Comment: I dont need to put data, it has data, check the LOG. I need to grab the fieldname `Contact__c` from the Array inside the List.

Comment: You can use `susc.get(loField)`. If it is returning data so, it is an expected field else you will not get data. Possibly run into error. @BoDiE2003