# Retrieve parent values from getPopulatedFieldsAsMap?

Tags: apex, custom-object, map

This question is related to help I received on a separate question: [Get fieldnames from List](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/165778/get-fieldnames-from-list).

I have since implemented this code:

```
for (DopplerListSubscriber__c susc : sobjList) {
    Map<String,Object> fieldsPopulated = susc.getPopulatedFieldsAsMap();
    System.debug(fieldsPopulated);
}
```

I'm getting the following debug log:

> 15:59:58:141 USER_DEBUG [35]|DEBUG|{Contact__c=00346000002O4YlAAK, Contact__r=Contact:{Id=00346000002O4YlAAK, Name=Jack Rogers, Email=jrogers@burlington.com}, DopplerList__c=a0046000001OvCGAA0, Id=a0246000001nTMdAAM}

The problem is, how do I access to `Name` and `Email` fields from the `Contact__r` key? That is:

```
Contact__r=Contact:{Id=00346000002O4YlAAK, Name=Jack Rogers, Email=jrogers@burlington.com}
```

Comment: the __r is a notification it is a Lookup reference. This means that you are getting a reference to the object identified by the Id in the field. Essentially, you can use it like an SObject.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Contact__r looks like it's an object. You can get the object by doing this:

```
Contact cnt = (Contact)fieldsPopulated.get('Contact__r');
system.debug('Email: ' + cnt.Email);
system.debug('Name : ' + cnt.Name);
```

==UPDATE (Per Comments)==

If you don't know the type of object that will be returned you can do this

```
Object obj = fieldsPopulated.get('Contact__r');
system.debug('Email: ' + obj.get('Email'));
system.debug('Name : ' + obj.get('Name'));
```

Comment: I cannot cast to `Contact` object since I have dynamic objects which I need to get before I get the field value.

Comment: You have to cast to a specific object, because that is the type that is returned by the method. I've added some code

Comment: You don't *have* to cast the object type per se. You could store it as an `SObject` and use dynamic `get` methods (you're not even taking advantage of static getters anyway).

Comment: That's what my updated code shows.... not sure if you saw the update

Comment: The last code is much more usefull for the case Im implementing it in, but it says the next `Error:(38, 30) Method does not exist or incorrect signature: [Object].get(String)`

Comment: Try casting it to an 'sObject'.

Answer (score 1):

I will prefer to write this logic to find out the field types.

`getFieldType()` method will take parameters like SObject and fieldName and will return the field type.

```
for (DopplerListSubscriber__c susc : sobjList) {
    Map<String,Object> fieldsPopulated = susc.getPopulatedFieldsAsMap();

    //since fieldsPopulated is returning
    /*
    {Contact__c=00346000002O4YlAAK, Contact__r=Contact:{Id=00346000002O4YlAAK, 
    Name=Jack Rogers, Email=jrogers@burlington.com}, 
    DopplerList__c=a0046000001OvCGAA0, Id=a0246000001nTMdAAM}
    */

    Set<String> fields = fieldsPopulated.keySet();
    for(String str:fields)
    {
        Schema.DisplayType dt = getFieldType(Contact, str);

        if(fd.getType() == Schema.DisplayType.String)
        {                       
            //handle String type and retrieve values from API Name
            System.debug((String) fieldsPopulated.get(str));
        }
    }
}

public Schema.DisplayType getFieldType(SObject obj, fieldName)
{
    Map<string, schema.sobjectfield> fieldMap = obj.getDescribe().fields.getMap();
    if (fieldMap != null)
    {
        // Loop through all fields.
        for (Schema.SObjectField f : fieldMap.values())
        {
            // Describe each field.
            Schema.DescribeFieldResult fd = f.getDescribe();
            if(fd.getName().equals(fieldName)
            {
                return fd.getType();
            }                           
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: it says `cannot resolve symbol 'fieldName'` on `public Schema.DisplayType getFieldType(SObject obj, fieldName)`